# JVM profiling - load test automation and comparison

Tags: testing, automation, jvm, profiling, integration-testing

How can I automate load test analysis? I have to run load tests and analyze memory, CPU, heap, GC activity and other basic stats. I want to record the stats (just like VisualVM or other tools) and compare them. I am looking for Linux command line tool that can profile the JVM and create files which I can compare or open it in VisualVM like tools.

Answer (score 1):

The Swiss Java Knife tool is pretty useful for getting data from a JVM on the command line.

https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools/blob/master/sjk-core/COMMANDS.md